# I checked "use custom manifest" and now I broke the Android Manifest and I don't know how to revert my change

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I experimented a bit with custom android manifests, and now I'm here with a broken manifest and I'd like to let unity regenerate the manifest. How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance &

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd imagine that if you unchecked the option to use a custom manifest, it would disregard the manifest you added. If you want to reset the manifest you were editing, you could just start a new project and copy and paste the manifest from that project. It's a pretty sparse file normally until the build populates it.

Comment: Thank you! I reimported the project ;D that fixed it.

Comment: I was going to add that making sure you are using a system for version control will definitely help you avoid troublesome issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

Reimporting the project fixed it.